# Check if Storage is Empty Ionic 4 Storage plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am fairly new to Angular/TypeSript/Ionic 4 so this may be a bi silly but I am using the Ionic Storage plugin,  , that you can find in this page "https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage". And I am running into 
my fair share of troubles. The documentation is clear but too simple.

I need to check if my storage is empty and also see the content of my storage.

First, I tried going about it through the length, expecting it to return a number but with this code on the service :

```
getLenght(){
    return this.storage.length().then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
}
```

and this code on my page I get a object result:

```
   storageLength : any; // it would give me error as a Number
clearStorage() {
    this.dataStorageService.clear();
    this.storageLength = this.dataStorageService.getLenght(); // returns object promise
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.storageLength)); 
//{"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":[]}
```

then I tried this instead but can't even run this, because of the error :

```
this.storage.get("qrCodeData").then( this.storage.get("qrCodeData") =>{}).catch(err=>{
    console.log("Your data don't exist and returns error in catch: " + JSON.stringify(err);
    });
```

error is "Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => any'.
  Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(value: any): any'"

So not sure how to verify if the storage is emtpy, since I am running into all sort of problems, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this  :

```
getLength() { 
 return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.get('qrCodeData').then((data) => {
        if(data){
          resolve(data);
        }    
      });    
    })    
}
```

And if the data is empty, data will be undefined so you can check it.

Comment: hello @Sam , thanks for answering, your function seems to return the exact same as my first try function the "getLengthFirstTry(){return this.storage.length().then((res) => {return res;}); }"  it returns the object promise that you can read with JSON.stringify on a alert, is there any other way to read it? or obtain a number? I am looking for a more appropriated way to do this "check if empty"?

Comment: I think its the only way. You can only check like that if the value is empty.

Comment: the value is never emtpy because it's an Object Promise with the following content "{"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":[]}"

Comment: You can try to parse it before and check if the string is empty.

Comment: how would you do that @Sam?

Comment: The problem is  normally  storage return an object undefined if it is empty, i really don't understand why u received an json object.

Comment: I know above is just an example, but be careful with it since it will not resolve if there is no data.  It also doesn't handle error rejections (for example, if storage isn't ready when this is called).  That may cause the promise to never return as it is coded above.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear exactly what you are storing, or exactly what you are trying to achieve.  That said, dealing with the promise info returned from this Storage module is a lot cleaner if you use async/await in my opinion.  An example is below.

```
let qrInfo = await this.getQrCodeData();
console.log(`Here is the result: ${qrInfo}`);  

...

async getQrCodeData(): Promise<string> {    
    await this.storage.ready();
    let qrCodeInfo = await this.storage.get("qrCodeData");
    return (qrCodeInfo) ? JSON.stringify(qrCodeInfo) : "";
}
```

Comment: as the name of the function says I want to get some QRCodes that will be stored in ionic storage , thanks for this answer, I assume I should make all my storage calls assync right?  that is probably the best way with async and wait, I will try to add this to my app then

Comment: Any function that uses `await` needs to be marked as `async`.  If you don't like async/await, you can just work with the promises with `then`, but I think that becomes less readable/maintainable. The Ionic Storage API naturally returns promises on `ready()` checks as well as `get`, `set`, `remove`, etc.  So you would need to return a promise in some fashion, no matter what.